# Can I install gcloud Auth in a python environment for a dbt project connecting to BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery, gcloud, dbt

I have a DBT project on cli/core I need to connect to my BigQuery account.

I ran dbt debug and got an error on the connection test with my dbt-bigquery adaptor saying: "dbt was unable to connect to the specified database"

I ran gcloud auth application-default login to no avail.

Then I ran gcloud init to no avail.

I then downloaded and installed the Google Cloud SDK on my laptop but not in that environment and confirmed the version but I still get the error in my python environment.

The error being - 'gcloud is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file'

Do I need to install gcloud again  within my python environment for the command, "gcloud auth application-default login" to work within my environment?

Comment: please share the exact errors that you get, so that we can help you

Comment: "gcloud is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file"

Comment: Please edit your post to include new information and not via comments. Also, include details on how you installed gcloud in your environment. The installation and setup is something you must do, DBT does not include Google Cloud tools.

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley I did that already when I made the comment. The errors are specified in my post in quotation marks